# Javascript: Renaming built in functions

Tags: javascript, renaming

In Javascript, is it acceptable to rename built in functions. For example, in my code, I use `document.querySelector()` tons of times. This is extremely long and tedious to type every single time (even with autocomplete from the IDE's side). Therefore, I decided to create a new function with a shorter name like the following:

`let qs = selector => document.querySelector(selector);`

Is this an acceptable practice in the JS community? Is this considered bad code? If so, why? Additionally, if doing this is alright, what are some drawbacks?

Thanks.

Comment: It's fine (it's more DRY, after all, which is almost always good), though I'd highly recommend `const` by default rather than `let`

Comment: One drawback I can think of: it's going to be a stumbling block for someone new to the codebase.

Comment: @CertainPerformance However, what exactly do you mean by "dry"? And yes, i meant `const`, not `let` :) Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks for the reply. it's a pretty small codebase (less than 10,000 LoC), so not sure that it would be big deal.

Comment: @YangK "Dry" is short for "do not repeat yourself". Basically DRY = less repetition in your code, which is almost always a positive.

Answer (score 3):

No. 
Someone is going to come behind you to edit your code. 
They will then have to track down your renaming function to actually see what it does. 
Create an snippet in your IDE if it’s that much of an issue for you.

Comment: Thanks mate. This is exactly what I was wondering about :)

Comment: No problem at all!