# How can I make an alias for element.querySelector?

Tags: javascript, html

For example, my element is a DOM element `div`, and within it are other `div`s.

So I generally use `elem.querySelector('.whatever')` to find a child within it. But I'd like to rename `querySelector` to `find`.

But how can I do this for all DOM elements, is there an easy way? I'd rather not just have "function find(elem, what)", but rather I'd like to do it on the element itself so "elem.find('.whatever')"

Comment: Is using jquery is a no? They have the `.find` method

Comment: @ThanhTrung yes I know, but I want to use vanilla javascript.

Comment: I was looking for something like this and saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53330996/javascript-renaming-built-in-functions).

Comment: While it's not advised, it's what the OP wanted.

Comment: @IvanGanchev I don't want it for the entire document, just within a specified element.

Comment: Something like this `var qs = (elem, selector) => elem.querySelector(selector);`? I don't think it's a good idea, but JavaScript doesn't mind.

Comment: While this can be done, extending the prototype of built-in objects is widely considered harmful and violates a golden development rule "**Do not modify objects you don't own.**". And you especially don't do it with a term that sounds very much like TC39 might make use of some time in the future like `find`.

Comment: Instead of aliasing consider using an IDE with intellisense like VSCode. This keeps your code cleaner and easier to understand while avoiding obscure bugs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function to achieve the same thing, but will give extra work to the browser

```
HTMLElement.prototype.find = function(selector){
    //or querySelector for one element depends on need
    return this.querySelectorAll(selector);
};

elem.find('.whatever');
```

Warning! Modifying the core prototype is a bad practice.

Another solution from "connexo"

```
HTMLElement.prototype.find = HTMLElement.prototype.querySelector
```

You can also create your own version of "jquery" if you are afraid of modifying the core prototype

```
function $$(element) {
    return {
        find: function(selector) {
            return element.querySelectorAll(selector);
        }
    }
}

//then just wrap any object
$$(elem).find(selector);
```

Comment: thanks that worked, but edit your answer to this.querySelector (not this.querySelect) and I'll set it to the answer.

Comment: While this can be done, extending the prototype of built-in objects is widely considered harmful and violates a golden development rule "***Do not modify objects you don't own.***". And you especially don't do it with a term that sounds very much like TC39 could make use of some time in the future like `find`.

Comment: Also, why not much simpler `HTMLElement.prototype.find = HTMLElement.prototype.querySelector`. **But again, this is considered really bad practice.**

Comment: @connexo You are right. But the OP wants an alias. Got better idea?

Comment: `[...document.all].forEach(el => el.find = HTMLElement.prototype.querySelector);`. Obviously this would not work for dynamically added elements, after this call.

Comment: That's adding method to existing objects. It's not really an alias.

Comment: You cannot alias prototype methods **on the prototype** without modifying it, so I suggested a solution that would achieve the same result for static pages *without modifying the prototype*. If, ffs, you **must** do it, at least use a name that TC39 will definitely **never use**, like `HTMLElement.prototype.$q = HTMLElement.prototype.querySelector`

Comment: Or use jquery, `$(..)` shortest

Comment: See this for why you shouldn't use `find`: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-flatMap/pull/56#issue-173327251

Answer (score -1):

I almost always use the global `document.querySelector` form, and it's definitely too verbose for my taste.

While not exactly an alias, I really like this simple solution:

```js
function get (selector, context=document) {
   return context.querySelector(selector)
}

function getAll (selector, context=document) {
   return context.querySelectorAll(selector)
}


// get single element
get("#id")

// get all elements
getAll("nav li")

// all within an element
getAll("li", element)
```

Comment: Obviously, you can rename to `find` and `findAll`.

Comment: I won't downvote, but this is exactly what I didn't want

Comment: `get` is reserved word for defining accessor properties.

Comment: Even if you were right, these are variable names and not properties (where the `get` syntax applies). In addition, both of these are valid: `{ get(){} }` and even `{ get get(){} }`.